# GNUS - how to persist "R" (read) state of the email back to gmail?

Tags: spacemacs, gnus

When I read an email in `gnus`, the email state changes to read whose symbol is `R`, The problem is that when I then open gmail on the browser I find that the already read email is still marked as **unread**.

what should i do to sync it back to Rsync?

Comment: can you edit your auestion including your gnu setup from the init file, please?

Comment: How are you connecting to Gmail? Are you using `nnimap` directly to Gmail, or do you use a local sync tool of some kind?